# Get the country of latitude/longitude offline

Tags: android

Can we get the country if we know latitude and longitude?

I'm having an offline scenario:
I need to get the country when there is no data as well. I have idea to use GeoCoder which gets the country when there is network.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Looked into anything? Considered anything? it took me two seconds to think of using a database which contains the rough lat./long. values for each country, but I assume that's too coarse? We need more details, or at least a reason to help you

Comment: you can think the database idea in 2 seconds .. but is there any implementation to store the every latlong of countries in this world. Note : country doesn't mean a single latitude longitude... It does mean a set of values and boundaries present for that country. Please suggest a solution Matt

Comment: A good suggestion here http://stackoverflow.com/a/6355183/264822

Answer (score 3):

I think the only way for that to work offline will be to have everything stored in a database locally. After a request to GeoCoder is made, you can cache the result, but for everything to work offline, the data has to already be on the device.

Comment: But, my customer visits different countries. Any ways ..thanks much for the help.... I didn't figured out a way as of now...