# Google Geocode address near a point?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I'm attempting to use Google Geocode to convert a textual address to a longitude/latitude position.

Sometimes, the geocoding operation fails (e.g. the city name is listed as "Rouyn Centre Rouyn-Noranda" instead of "Rouyn-Noranda"). Now, it just so happens that I've got a longitude/latitude point that is near the desired address (say within 1km of the actual address).

**Is there a way to look up the coordinates of a street name, number** (excluding city, postal code and country) **that is "near" a second point**?

Comment: Actually forget that... I think your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159074/given-the-lat-long-coordinates-how-can-we-find-out-the-city-country

Comment: @CliffRibaudo, I know how to reverse geocode. The question is how to restrict forward geocoding to addresses close to a point. Reverse geocoding alone is not the answer.

Comment: Yeah... so not really sure why Borgwardt's answer or the other one don't cover it. There is no easy answer to your question. You're going to have to do work.

Comment: *look up the coordinates of a street name, number that is "near" a second point* - That is called [biaising](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingViewports).

Answer (score 0):

You could test any subsequent points to see if they're within 1km of the original point using [google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical).