# The country belonging to a location (python)?

Tags: python, location, geopy

Via

[Given the lat/long coordinates, how can we find out the city/country?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159074/given-the-lat-long-coordinates-how-can-we-find-out-the-city-country)

I tried to get information from the coordinates, and it works, as Farsheed writes in python. But can I get only the country as answer, does it exist such an attribute to give 'location' variable?

Comment: It can give you anything you want as long as you have the data for it.

Comment: Doesn't `location.raw['address']['country']` contain what you want?

Comment: This is is what i was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
>>> geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="specify_your_app_name_here")
>>> location = geolocator.reverse("52.509669, 13.376294")
>>> print(location.address)
Potsdamer Platz, Mitte, Berlin, 10117, Deutschland, European Union
>>> print((location.latitude, location.longitude))
(52.5094982, 13.3765983)
>>> print(location.raw)
{'place_id': '654513', 'osm_type': 'node', ...}
```

Comment: The Question asked how one can get the country. Update your answer to demonstrate how.