# How to use javascript Geolocation to change a boolean

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I was wondering if it is possible to use Javascript Geolocation to change a variable?

[image]

As in- if I am in California, then my Javascript geolocation code will return true. But if I am somewhere else it will return false.

```
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Yes there are certainly ways to do this.

Comment: How might that be?

Comment: Sure. But, personally, I would get the `true`/`false` based on the time zone of the user. Much simpler and no API call.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Given the lat/long coordinates, how can we find out the city/country?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159074/given-the-lat-long-coordinates-how-can-we-find-out-the-city-country)

Comment: That is a better idea for sure @Scott Marcus.