# Get country isocode from latitude longitude Java

Tags: java, geolocation, coordinates

I have a latitude and a longitude , and I need to get the isocode , is there any Library in Java or Google service library that returns me the isocode ?

Comment: Hi, have you done any research, prior to posting your question, on this topic ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Given the lat/long coordinates, how can we find out the city/country?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159074/given-the-lat-long-coordinates-how-can-we-find-out-the-city-country)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data are not fixed, it is impossible to put that into a library. You need to call a service, e.g. the GeoCoder from here.com: https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/dev_guide/topics/what-is.html