# how can I convert latitude, longitude to address when internet is off in flutter?

Tags: flutter, geolocation, latitude-longitude

In short I want to fetch address from latitude longitude at offline mode.
I've tried this [geocoder](https://pub.dev/packages/geocoding) package. but this is required internet to get address from latitude longitude

###### Tried so far

```
static getCurrentLocationAddress() async {
    try {
      List<Placemark> listPlaceMarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
          currentPosition.latitude, currentPosition.longitude);
      Placemark place = listPlaceMarks[0];
      currentLocationAddress =
          "${place.country}, ${place.locality}, ${place.administrativeArea}";
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

I just want same think but without internet requirement.

Any answer and suggestions are most welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/location

this will help for you

Comment: shubham sir, this package isn't return address. Have a look on question I want address from latitude and longitude without accessing internet.

Comment: Hi @abdul sorry to say but it is not possible to do it into offline you must required internet connection to do this task also have a look into this answer maybe this will work for you 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159074/given-the-lat-long-coordinates-how-can-we-find-out-the-city-country/6355183#6355183

Comment: I've already gone through this answer. thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can only get your address by location using this package using the internet.
It's not possible to get an address without using the internet.

https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator